# Add permission to folder

Tags: c#, .net, permissions

How i Can Get All Users Name to Add one permission to the selected folder and take
If anyone knows please tell me how get all users in windows server and windows to get name of them to add or remove users from having permission to the folder
somthing like this  Prodesk\Meepo Prodesk\sadeghi BUILTIN\Administrator NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM in windows and windows server

```
DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(folderPath);`
    AuthorizationRuleCollection authorizationRules = 
    directorySecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true
     typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));

                    Control.Instance.listb1.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in authorizationRules)
                    {
                        var identity = rule.IdentityReference.Value.ToString();
                        if (identity != string.Empty)
                        {

                            Control.Instance.listb1.Items.Add(rule.IdentityReference.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value.ToString());
                        } `
```

i try this but its just for folder users i want to get all users names like this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List all UPN Suffixes from Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916187/list-all-upn-suffixes-from-active-directory)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.